# Using QDigest over a date range

Tags: presto

I need to keep a 28 day history for some dashboard data.  Essentially I have an event/action that is recorded through our BI system.  I want to count the number of events and the distinct users who do that event for the past 1 day, 7 days and 28 days.  I also use grouping sets (cube) to get the fully segmented data by country/browser/platform etc.

The old way was to do this keeping a 28 day history per user, for all segments.  So if a user accessed the site from mobile and desktop every day for all 28 days they would have 54 rows in the DB.  This ends up being a large table and is time consuming even to calculate approx_distinct and not distinct.  But the issue is that I also wish to calculate approx_percentiles.

So I started investigating the user of HyperLogLog https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/hyperloglog.html
This works great, its much more efficient storing the sketches daily rather than the entire list of unique users per day.  As I am using approx_distinct the values are close enough and it works.

I then noticed a similar function for medians. Qdigest.
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/qdigest.html
Unfortunately the documentation is not nearly as good on this page as it is on previous pages, so it took me a while to figure it out.  This works great for calculating daily medians.  But it does not work if I want to calculate the median actions per user over the longer time period.  The examples in HyperLogLog demonstrate how to calculate approx_distinct users over a time period but the Qdigest docs do not give such an example.

The results that I get when I try something to the HLL example for date ranges with Qdigest I get results similar to 1 day results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're in need of medians that are aggregated (summed) across multiple days on a per user basis, you'll need to perform that aggregation prior to insertion into the qdigest in order for this to work for 7- and 28-day per-user counts.  In other words, the units of the data need to be consistent, and if daily values are being inserted into qdigest, you can't use that qdigest for 7- or 28-day per-user counts of the events.